# How to extract html to text in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to browse an html page and try to get the data i need using BeautifulSoup. everything looks good but i am hitting a wall and got stuck.

What i need to accomplish is to extract this 9h7a2m value from this line :

```
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3
```

The result im getting is this :

```
<p>D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string</p>
<p><span id="more-1203"></span></p>
<p>D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3.string<br/>
<p>pinging test is positive but no works</p>
<p>how much time are online?</p>
<p><input aria-required="true" id="author" name="author" size="22" tabindex="1" type="text" value=""/>
<label for="author"><small>Name (required)</small></label></p>
<p><input aria-required="true" id="email" name="email" size="22" tabindex="2" type="text" value=""/>
<label for="email"><small>Mail (will not be published) (required)</small></label></p>
<p><input id="url" name="url" size="22" tabindex="3" type="text" value=""/>
<label for="url"><small>Website</small></label></p>
<p><textarea cols="100%" id="comment" name="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>
<p><input id="submit" name="submit" tabindex="5" type="submit" value="Submit Comment"/>
<input id="comment_post_ID" name="comment_post_ID" type="hidden" value="41"/>
<input id="comment_parent" name="comment_parent" type="hidden" value="0"/>
</p>
<p style="display: none;"><input id="akismet_comment_nonce" name="akismet_comment_nonce" type="hidden" value="1709964457"/></p>
<p style="display: none;"><input id="ak_js" name="ak_js" type="hidden" value="99"/></p>
```

At the end i need to save it to a text file.

My code :

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# mechanize 

mech = mechanize.Browser()
mech.set_handle_robots(True)   
mech.set_handle_refresh(True)  
mech.addheaders =  [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
url = ('http://example.com/')
response = mech.open(url)
resp = response.read()

# beautifulsoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)
soup.prettify()



# test code



for i in soup.find('div',{'id':'content'}).findAll('p'):

    print i
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it using a regular expression:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your html here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

s = soup.find('p').br.previous_sibling  # find "p" element and get the part before the 1st br
match = re.search('string\-1\.string2 \d+ (\w+) string3\.string', s)
print match.group(1)
```

prints `9h7a2m`.

---

UPD (real web-site):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = urlopen('your URL here')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

entry = soup.find('div', class_="entry")

for p in entry.find_all('p'):
    for row in p.find_all(text=True):
        try:
            print row.split(' ')[-2]
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

Comment: i get this error    `print match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @Al1nuX sure you do :) I've tested the code on the input you've provided. The real input you have is probably something different.

Comment: but i am pasting my exact output that i am getting from the code above.

Comment: its strange, i tried your code by itself and it works, but when i try to add it to my code it does not. and i need also to print the full line first, then extract the word. for example D: string-1.string2 15030 9h7a2m string3

Comment: @Al1nuX what is the value of `s` when you run your code?

Comment: check your gist, i have added a comment. when i try the `s` i get an empty screen.

Comment: you are the best :), im ashamed of my code lol, your code looks neat. cant we do this with mechanize? im new to all this thanks allot for your code.

Comment: @Al1nuX nope, mechanize is for programmatic web-browsing, for parsing html you need an HTML parser, like `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58044/discussion-between-al1nux-and-alecxe).